# How to run all command with same name into a notebook

Tags: notebooks

I have a very big notebook with a command repeated a lot of times but with different parameters each time and I want to run all these commands at the same time without having to run separately all of them. Is there a way?

**EDIT: more info**

Between different calls of the 'command' there are other things (mainly plots) and I want to preserve the order of the notebook.

Using the `Evaluate Notebook` form the menu `Evaluation` can be an option but when I am in a hurry this is bad because it evaluates also all the things in between while I am mainly interested in the output of my commands.

Comment: Any reason not to just merge the cells into one, or better yet, change the 'command' to accept arguments and then map/table over the different parameters?

Comment: @rasher between different calls of my 'command' there are things and I want to preserve this ordering for formatting reasons

Comment: Ah, ok then, what about the `Evaluate Notebook` menu item?
NVM - I missed the 'same name' part...

Comment: @rasher I added more info in the question

Comment: You could mark the cells you don't want evaluated as such in the cell menu (you can collectively do this). Otherwise, probably some notebook programming involved.

Comment: @rasher but if in a second moment I want to evaluate a cell marked 'not evaluable' I have to remark it 'evaluable'. What about evaluate only cells with a certain tag?

Comment: Yes, just was about to type that! Use tags on the cells you want (same tag for all), then `NotebookLocate` and `SelectionEvaluate` together.

Comment: @rasher your solution is better than mine, if you turn it in an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested:

Use tags on the cells you want (same tag for all), then `NotebookLocate` and`SelectionEvaluate` together.

Answer (score 4):

I get it using this code:

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[];
NotebookEvaluate[nb, InsertResults -> True, EvaluationElements -> {"Tags" -> {"evaluate"}}];
```

and tagging with the tag `evaluate` only the cells that I want to evaluate on first run.